# How to create a bone that move but constrained by 2 bones

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, constraints

I’m trying to animate the movement of the back door of a Lego star war gunship with bones. I captured what movement I want in the following video.

[Lego Star Wars - Blender Rigging Problem](https://youtu.be/yAGVG0ummwc)

In the first part, this is what I want. In the second part, we can see that the bone R_BackDoor is not constrained by the 2 arm bones when I would like to.

My problem is, I cannot find the right bone constraint to obtain the first part of my video.

Could someone please help me with that ?

A real life reference if needed : [Lego Star Wars Custom Republic Gunship REVIEW](https://youtu.be/5GNHFgSoh1A?t=169)

Anoter point of view not showed in either video. If you need others pictures, don't hesitate.
[image: Picture from under]

Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need only 3 bones for this.

[image]

bone.002 and bone are connected.

bone.002 has a damped track to bone.003

[image]

bone.003 has a copy location to bone

[image]

result:

[image]

when i made the animation i had another bone, which just has a copy rotation to bone, but it isn't really necessary. But maybe you want it for the second "guide arm".

Comment: Yes it was that! Thank you very much for your help! I had to tweek the axis because the door is leaning but everything work.

Comment: You are welcome